# Doubly linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list

While I'm training to get better at C, I tried my hand at making a doubly linked list implementation.

#### `linkedlist.h`

```
#ifndef LINKED_LIST_H_
#define LINKED_LIST_H_

#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    void* data;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
} node;

typedef node* pnode;

typedef struct List {
    pnode head, tail;
} *List;

List init_list();
void push_back(List, void*);
void* pop_back(List);
void push_front(List, void*);
void* pop_front(List);
void foreach(List, void (*func)(void*));
void free_list(List);
void clear(List);
int size(List);


#endif /* LINKED_LIST_H_ */
```

#### `linkedlist.c`

```
#include "linkedlist.h"

List init_list() {
    List list = (List)malloc(sizeof(struct List));
    list->head = NULL;
    list->tail = NULL;
    return list;
}

void push_back(List list, void* data) {
    pnode temp = (pnode)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = NULL;
    temp->prev = NULL;

    if(!(list->head)) {
         list->head = temp;
         list->tail = temp;
    } else {
        list->tail->next = temp;
        temp->prev = list->tail;
        list->tail = list->tail->next;
    }
}

void push_front(List list, void* data) {
    pnode temp = (pnode)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = NULL;
    temp->prev = NULL;

    if(!(list->tail)) {
         list->head = temp;
         list->tail = temp;
    } else {
        list->head->prev = temp;
        temp->next = list->head;
        list->head = list->head->prev;
    }
}

void* pop_front(List list) {
    if(!(list->tail)) return NULL;
    pnode temp = list->head;

    if(list->head == list->tail) {
        list->head = list->tail = NULL;
    } else {
        list->head = list->head->next;
        list->head->prev = NULL;
    }
    void* data = temp->data;
    free(temp);
    return data;
}

void* pop_back(List list) {
    if(!(list->head)) return NULL;
    pnode temp = list->tail;

    if(list->tail == list->head) {
        list->tail = list->head = NULL;
    } else {
        list->tail = list->tail->prev;
        list->tail->next = NULL;
    }
    void* data = temp->data;
    free(temp);
    return data;
}

void free_list(List list) {
    while(list->head) {
        pop_back(list);
    }

    free(list);
}

void clear(List list) {
    while(list->head) {
        pop_back(list);
    }
}

void foreach(List list, void(*func)(void*)) {
    pnode temp = list->head;

    if(temp) {
        while(temp) {
            (*func)(temp->data);
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
}

int size(List list) {
    int i = 0;
    pnode temp = list->head;
    while(temp) {
        i++;
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    return i;
}
```

Can you please point out any flaws, errors, stupid mistakes, general improvements, which can make this code better and "C'ish"?

Comment: Why are you defining struct type aliases?

Comment: @Calak Because, I don't want to keep writing struct again and again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome on Code Review

## Generalities

#### Includes

You don't need `#include <stdlib.h>` in `linkedlist.h`, so remove it and instead, just add it in `linkedlist.c`  right after `#include linkedlist.h`.

#### Name collisions

I'll discuss no more this subject after but be aware that names like `node`, `list`, `size` or `clear` for example, are very usual and subject to collisions. Consider using more robust names, maybe with a prefix.

#### Usable interface

Since the user look at your header file to know how to use your functions, a good habit is to to name the arguments, that's make the interface more explicit. Furthermore, adding documentation as comments about your interface help them to use it correctly.

#### Use the `const` keyword

Read [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/204500/when-and-for-what-purposes-should-the-const-keyword-be-used-in-c-for-variables) and [this](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/dosearchsite.action?queryString=const) to know when et how.

#### Assertions and error-checking

You *could* use assertions to check preconditions, postconditions and invariants. It make your code more explicit and you avoid possibly broke you code when modifying.

- [How to use assertions in C](https://ptolemy.berkeley.edu/~johnr/tutorials/assertions.html)
- [How and When to Use C's assert() Macro](https://barrgroup.com/Embedded-Systems/How-To/Use-Assert-Macro)
- [Why should I use asserts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081409/why-should-i-use-asserts) (for C++ but still applicable)

---

## `struct node`

#### `[typedef] struct [tag] { ... } [alias];`

Personally, I try to avoid to use sames ''*struct tag*'' and ''*typedef name*'' if I have to typedef a `struct`. It's completely a [matter of taste](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20552739/2644192), since "*modern*" compilers (for more than 20 years)  can handle this easily, but so, user know when he work with the tag or the alias.

But there are many others "conventions":

- [Some](https://stackoverflow.com/a/252810/2644192) prefer "*untagged aliased `struct`*" (if there are no self-referencing members).
- Where [others](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4566358/2644192) says to [never](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/process/coding-style.html#typedefs) typedef a `struct`.
- ...

#### Consistency

No matter [where you place asterisk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180401/placement-of-the-asterisk-in-pointer-declarations) for pointers, try to be consistent through your code:

```
void* data;
    ^ LEFT-ALIGNED
struct node *next;
            ^ RIGHT-ALIGNED
```

([here](https://www.quora.com/Where-should-I-put-the-asterisk-for-pointers-in-C++-Is-it-int*-ptr-int-*-ptr-or-int-*ptr) is another talk on this endless debate)

So **IMHO**, this is cleaner:

```
typedef struct node node_t;
typedef node_t* node_ptr;

struct node {
    void* data;
    node_ptr next;
    node_ptr prev;
};
```

---

## `struct List`

#### Consistency

The first letter of the `struct node` is **lowercase**, while the first of the `struct List` is **uppercase**.

#### Variables declaration

Try to don't declare several variables on the same line, it will avoid you [many problems](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/DCL04-C.+Do+not+declare+more+than+one+variable+per+declaration).

```
typedef struct list list_t;
typedef list_t* list_ptr;

struct list {
    node_ptr head;
    node_ptr tail;
};
```

---

## `init_list()`, `push_back()`, `push_front()`

- There's no need to cast the return type of `malloc` from `void*` since it's implicitly converted to any pointer type.
- You can also omit the `struct`  as you aliases it.
- Optionally, you could make more concise using `calloc` and rid of the manual initialization of `next` and `prev` (with few costs).
- Since you have a `free_list` function, consider renaming `init_list` to  `alloc_list`
- For `push_*` function, you should use `sizeof *list->head`  instead of using the type. It's easier to maintain. (e.g. if you modify the node type latter, the change here is automatic)
- For `push_*` function, you *could* return an `int`, an `enum` or a `bool` (via `<stdbool.h>`)  to indicate the success of the insert (since the `malloc` can fail) or a pointer to the new created node (and so `NULL` in case of fail). No matter how but **you should always handle errors when using `malloc`**

## `pop_back()`, `pop_front()`

- I find multiples assignments on same line less readable, but that's my opinion.
- *For info: On some not-wide-used platforms (PalmOS, 3BSD, and other non ANSI-C compatibles), you should check for NULL before freeing to avoid crashes.*

## `clear()`

- You could rewrite the cleaning algorithm to be more efficient since you discard return values.

## `free_list()`

- Simply use `clear` before freeing, to avoid code duplication.

Comment: @Calac, awesome answer! I'm not the OP, but I really enjoyed reading the post. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The method `free_list(list)` should internally use `clear(list)`, instead of duplicating the code for clearing the list.

The method `clear(list)` should not use `pop_back(list)`, which does a lot of checks and pointer assignments, which are discarded by the next `pop_back()` call. Instead, maintain a local variable and loop over the list and free the nodes directly.  Then, unconditional set head & tail to NULL.  Eg:

```
void clear(List list) {
    pnode curr = list->head;
    while (curr) {
        pnode temp = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
        free(temp);
    }
    list->head = NULL;
    list->tail = NULL;
}
```